# Property of Rational Numbers

Tags: order-theory, cardinals

Is there a name for the property of the rational ordered field that given any enumeration of the set of rational numbers used to define this ordered field, meaning a bijection between the rational numbers and the natural numbers $~f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$, the following is true:
$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\exists q\in\mathbb{Q},\forall m
\in\{1,2,\dots,n\},(~f(m)\lt q\lt 0~)\lor(~0\lt q\lt f(m)~)$.
The reason I ask, is that I want to know what to call this kind of density of an ordered field (where you can enumerate, but not in order of magnitude).

Comment: But this is not true. Specifically, the first $m$ such that $f(m)\leq 0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I think you are asking about is order-denseness. A linear order $<$ on a set $S$ is called order-dense (or order-dense in itself) iff whenever $x,y \in S$ with $x<y$ there exists $z\in S$ with $x<z<y.$  And if $T\subset S$ we say $T$ is order-dense in $S$ iff whenever $x,y\in S$ with $x<y$ there exists $z\in T$ with $x<z<y.$  So $\mathbb Q$ is order-dense in itself, but $\mathbb N$ is not.

Comment: Re: your last sentence, note that there are *no* enumerations of $\mathbb{R}$ at all.

Comment: I fixed the last sentence, good point.

Comment: @Alex What you wrote in the question is definitely false for any enumeration $f$, and what Arthur said proves as much. However, it becomes true if you replace $\mathbb Q$ with the set of _positive_ rationals.

Comment: Sorry I have to fix this, Jack and Arthur are correct.  I'll try to word to better get my idea across.

Comment: The property that you describe as "you can enumerate, but not in order of magnitude" sounds more like the fact that there exists no strictly increasing bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb Q$. That is, given any enumeration $f$, there must exist $n > m$ such that $f(n)<f(m)$. So the enumeration fails to count the rationals "in order".

Comment: @Jack This may be a better what to say what I'm getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're interested in the [order type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_type) of $\mathbb Q$. Two totally ordered sets are of the same order type iff there is a strictly increasing bijection between them. $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$ are of different order types, which is reflected in the fact that for example, between any two rationals there is another rational, but this is not the case for $\mathbb N$. $\mathbb N$ also has different order type to $\mathbb Z$, since $\mathbb Z$ is unbounded in both directions, whereas $\mathbb N$ is only unbounded in one direction.

Every ordered field contains a copy of $\mathbb Q$, because every ordered field is of characteristic zero, and every field of characteristic zero contains $\mathbb Q$. Thus no ordered field is order-isomorphic to $\mathbb N$.

You may also be interested in the notion of a [dense order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order). Every ordered field is dense, because if $a < b$, $\frac {a+b} 2$ is between $a$ and $b$. Proof:

$$\frac {a+b} 2 - a = \frac {b - a} 2 > 0$$

$$b - \frac {a + b} 2 = \frac {b - a} 2 > 0$$

...since $b-a>0$; and $\frac 1 2>0$, since $1$ is positive in any ordered field, therefore so is $2$, so if $\frac 1 2$ were negative, then $1$ would be as well.